# While using DataTable in R Shiny how to link or add rowCallback and formatStyle for formatting and displaying data

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am using two tabs to display a data frame in R Shiny. Is it possible to use and display both formatting features, rowCallback and stypeEqual, in one tab?

```
datatable(DF, options = list(rowCallback=JS("function(row,data) {
      data[0] = data[0] .replace(/NxG/g,'<span style=\"color:blue; font-weight:bold\"\">NxG</span>');
      $('td:eq(0)', row).html(data[0]  );}"), dom = 't'))

datatable(DF,options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = (2:5), visible = FALSE)))) %>% formatStyle(1, 3, backgroundColor = 
     styleEqual(c(1, 3), c('green', 'yellow')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it was a very simple solution.

```
datatable(DF, options = list(rowCallback=JS("function(row,data) {
      data[0] = data[0]  .replace(/NxG/g,'<span style=\"color:blue; font-weight:bold\"\">NxG</span>');
      $('td:eq(0)', row).html(data[0]  );}"  ), dom = 't')) %>%
      formatStyle(1, 3, backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1, 3), c('lightgreen', 'yellow', 'yellow')))
```